# How to apply a CGAffineTransform to a CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, vector, matrix, core-graphics

If I have a transformation matrix, as a `CGAffineTransform`, and a point, as a `CGPoint`, how can I get the matrix-vector product?

For those wondering why I'm asking, I'm looking for a way to transform points between user coordinates and device coordinates. The functions `CGContextConvertPointToUserSpace` and `CGContextConvertPointToDeviceSpace` only seem to work in `drawRect`. I want to be able to get touch input, coming from a gesture recognizer in device coordinates, and transform it to user coordinates using the saved transformation matrix (`CGContextGetCTM`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function [`CGPointApplyAffineTransform()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454251-cgpointapplyaffinetransform) seems to do what you want.

Comment: `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` has been replaced by instance method `CGPoint.applying(_:)`